# console.log processed before deferred object returned to .done

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

The Pluralsight tutorial on jQuery deferred objects has this example that I've added some `console.log`s to. It's loading three html files into three divs asynchronously, and on success it prints to screen 'Worked!'--however, the `console.log` is printing "success!" to the console before the processing is actually complete. Same thing if I put `console.log` within the `when` portion of code--it prints that content is finished loading before it actually loads up on screen.

So why does processing on the DOM occur as expected (on success), but `console.log` messages are printed earlier than success?

```
var loadSection = function (options) {
    if (typeof options !== 'object')
    options = {
    };
    options.selector = options.selector || '';
    options.url = options.url || '';
    return $.get(options.url, function (result) {
        $(options.selector).html(result);
        console.log(options.url)
    }, 'html')
}
$('#Load').on('click', function () {
    $.when(loadSection({
        url: 'Content1.html',
        selector: '#Section1'
    }), loadSection({
        url: 'Content2.html',
        selector: '#Section2'
    }), loadSection({
        url: 'Content3.html',
        selector: '#Section3'
    })
    ).promise()
     .done(function (result) {
        $('#Messages').append('Worked!<br/>')
        console.log('success!');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you calling `.promise()` on the result (a Deferred instance) of `$.when()`? You can just call `.done()` directly on that return value.

Comment: This is because the operations on the DOM is much slower than the JavaScript scripting

Comment: You should use `.then` intead of `.promise().done()`

Comment: The tutorial starts off with us using `.then`, but then has you change it to `.promise().done()` to prevent the state of the deferred object from being changed accidentally, i suppose via resolve/reject. i haven't made it that far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `loadSection` function, change

```
return $.get(options.url, function (result) {
    $(options.selector).html(result);
    console.log(options.url);
}, 'html')
```

to

```
return $.get(options.url, 'html')
.then(function (result) {
    console.log(options.url);
    return $(options.selector).html(result).promise();
});
```

this should return a promise that resolves when `.html(result)` is complete, rather than when `$.get` is complete